# In UFD every irreducible element is prime

Tags: ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I have seen the proof given earlier in a similar question here. But I have a confusion in that proof.
If $p$ be the irreducible element of the UFD $R$ with $p|ab$ , then, $ab=pc$ , for some $c \in R$.
Then at one point we can write $a,b,c$ as the unique product of irreducible elements since $R$ is UFD. 
Here my question is that why c is a non-unit(as a result of which we were able to factorize it since it is there in the defn only that for factorization the element must be non-unit).
Also in some other sites I saw that in this proof they have assumed $c$ to be non-unit,
but in a book which I follow in my university, it's written that it $c$ must be a non-unit. There is no such assumption there.But in that book the reason is not written, they have asked to prove it to the readers.
Any explanation will be of great help. Thankyou.

Comment: see [here](https://www.planetmath.org/IrreducibleOfAUFDIsPrime)

Comment: If $\ c\ $ is a unit, then $\ p=c^{-1}ab\ $.  Therefore, by the uniqueness of factorisation, one of $\ a\ $ or $\ b\ $ must be a unit and  $\ p\ $ must be an an associate of the other.

Comment: @lonza Then what is the contradiction?

Comment: There's no contradiction unless you've assumed that neither of $\ a\ $ or $\ b\ $ are units.  If  you haven't made that assumption then $\ c\ $ certainly *can* be a unit, but in that case $\ p\ $ must be an associate of $\ a\ $ or $\ b\ $, so it's still the case that $\ p\,|\,a\ $ or $\ p\,|\,b\ $.

Comment: @lonza Yes, in the proof we have assumed that none of a and b are units. Then can u plz explain what's the contradiction

Comment: Units can be *absorbed* into any irred, so $c\mid 1\,\Rightarrow\,$ RHS $=pc\,$ is also irreducible. By uniqueness it is *associate* to some irred $q$ in the factorization of the LHS, wlog from the factorization of $a,\,$ thus $\,p\mid pc\mid q\mid a\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ **QED** $\, $   This will be a special case of the general argument when done correcty.

Comment: If neither $\ a\ $ nor $\ b\ $ is a unit, then $\ ab\ $ must be divisible either by two distinct irreducible factors, or by the square of an irreducible. In either case, the identity $\ ab=pc\ $, where $\ p\ $ is irreducible and $\ c\ $ a unit, would violate the supposed uniqueness of the factorisation of $\ ab\ $ into irreducibles.